# Limit of ${x}^{\frac1{1-x}}$ as $x$ approaches 1

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following **homework** question, and I've been stuck on it for the last 2 hours. I have no idea how to find the answer.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to1} {x}^{\frac1{1-x}}$$

I have tried manipulating the equation so that I can use L'Hopitals to no avail. I think that I may have to take the natural log of it, however I am unsure of how to go about this.

The answer (As per WolframAlpha) is:

$$\frac1e$$

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might go about solving this.

Comment: The logarithm is $$\frac{1}{1-x}\log x.$$ Can you apply De l'Hospital?

Comment: @Siminore I understand how you got that, however, how do I relate this to the limit. We have only just started limits, so I am unsure of whether it now becomes:
$$\log\lim(x\to1, {x}^{\frac1{(1-x)}}) = \frac{1}{1−x}\log x$$

Comment: The idea is if $\lim_{x \to 1}\log (f(x)) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = e^L$, where log is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Alternatively, let $x = 1 + 1/y$ and let $y \to \pm\infty$.  Does the new limit look familiar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $y=x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$, then $$\log y = \frac{\log x}{1-x}.$$
This is also equal to $$-\frac{\log x -\log 1}{x-1},$$ and if you let $x \to 1$ you get, **by definition of derivative**,
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \log y = \left. -\frac{d}{dx}\log x \right|_{x=1}  = -1.
$$
Therefore, $\lim_{x \to 1} y = e^{-1}=1/e$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik it's okay. I can follow this...mostly :D.

Comment: Well, if he wants to use De l'Hospital's theorem, I suspect he knows derivatives!

Comment: If that is the case, I will be happy :D

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\exp\left({\frac{1}{1-x}\log x}\right)$$ By L'Hospital this converges to the same limit as $\dfrac{\frac{1}{x}}{-1}$ wich clearly goes to $-1$ as $x\to1$. So $$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\left(\exp\left({\frac{1}{1-x}\log x}\right)\right)=\exp(-1)=\frac1e$$